# Apple is Rejecting my Production Receipt

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, testflight

I've been developing this app for iOS and it has In-App Purchases. The app sends the purchase receipt to my server and my server ask Apple's server if the receipt is valid (tipical).

One of my testers made a purchase on the app with her own credit card and her own Apple account, not a guest account. But for some reason, **her receipt was reject by Apple** saying that it was a receipt for Sandbox, no for production.

*Does any of you guys have any idea why this might be happening?*

I mean, she bought it with her own credit card and Apple account. It shouldn't be Sanbos, should it? Is it maybe because she was using **TestFlight** maybe?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It's not an app from the app store so it uses the sandbox.

Comment: maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27734135/2557145) will help you.