# Using external test flight user

Tags: ios, swift, testflight

my first iOS app is going to have  `IAP` in it, should I upload build in test-flight before the implementation of `IAP` for external testers or implement IAP and then upload in test-flight.

If later is the answer then my next question of how external testers will test the app without creating testers in my App Store connect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TestFlight users don't require a sandbox account, but they will test against an automatically created sandbox account.

**Sandbox Accounts**

The moment a tester opens your application, a sandbox account is created for them. This means it's no longer necessary to create test accounts in iTunes Connect. Testing In-App Purchases was never easier.

Checkout the answers in stackoverflow link below.

[How to test In App Purchases through Apple TestFlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734090/how-to-test-in-app-purchases-through-apple-testflight/37042040#37042040)